# Simulate the disk I/O handling in system programming by a linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, priority-queue, systems-programming

Very Stuck on a C project! Need help on the following requirements, any help is appreciated:

1. **IORB structure:**
   Its data type is defined as:

   ```
   typedef struct iorb {
     int base_pri;
     struct iorb *link;
     char filler[100];
   } IORB;
   ```

   where `base_pri` is an integer representing the block’s base priority; `link` is a pointer to next block; `filler` is a description about the block which is opaque to the sorting routine.
2. **Separate source file for the priority computing function:**

   ```
   void sortList(IORB * head, int(*prio)(int));
   ```

   where head is a pointer to the linked list, and prio is a priority computing function.
   The sortList() implementation is to be in a separate source file from any driver code. If needed, Include other functions you’ll need for testing, such as those to build and display the list, in the same source file of the driver code.
3. **Priority computing function:**

   To keep things simple, scheduling priorities will be computed from a single integer field (named `base_pri`) in each IORB. You may design any computing method. The function is to return an integer representing the scheduling priority.
4. **Sorting algorithm:**

   You are required to use the Selection Sort algorithm to sort the list in ascending order. This algorithm finds the minimum value, swaps it with the value in the first position, and repeats these steps for the remainder of the list.
5. **Sorting in place:**

   The list must be sorted in place. This means that ONLY the links within the list may be altered, no IORB block may be copied to somewhere else in memory.
6. **Building and display the list:**

   The list is initially built by a function buildList().
   For each IORB in the list, its base scheduling priority base pri is calculated by a
   random number generator. You may assign any string to f iller.
   The list is displayed by a function displayList(), which shows the description, the
   base priority and priority of each element.

**Background:** 
This project is to simulate the disk I/O handling in system programming by a
linked list.
A particular Unix kernel operation handles disk I/O by allowing independent user
processes to place I/O request blocks (IORB) in a linked list. The order in which these
requests are serviced depends on their scheduling priority. The scheduling strategy is
adaptive, which simply means that the kernel may carry out different computations at
different times in order to calculate the priority value for each element of the list.
You are required to write a C program on Linux which designs, implements and tests
a sorting function: sortList(). The first argument of the function is a pointer to the head
of the list. The second argument is a priority computing function which computes and
returns the scheduling priority. The sorting function will sort such a list according to the
scheduling priority of each element. Since the OS will have other structures with pointers
to IORB blocks, the list must be sorted in place.

Comment: what is your question ? where are you blocked ?

Comment: `void sortList(IORB ∗ head, int(∗prio)(int));` with this prototype, the sorting routine will not be able to change the first (*head) node, as would be the case when a higher priority node would enter the queue.

Comment: @wildplasser A dummy head node, perhaps?

Comment: @user58697 : that is up to the OP

Comment: I am stuck on implementing the sort function: void sortList( IORB * head, int(*prio)(int)). I am not sure how to start or implement it. And some tips/ guidelines for the priority computing function would be helpful as well.